# Jquery .click ou function

Tags: jquery, html, estilo-de-codificação, semântica

Conforme vou me acostumando cada vez mais tenho deixado de lado

```
<input type=button onclick="TESTE()">

<script>
function TESTE(){
...
}
```

Para utilizar o método em jquery

```
<input type=button id="teste">
<script>
$("#teste").click(function() {
...
}
```

Sei que o jQuery é um método mais moderno, mas é melhor? ou posso ainda fazer uma salada entre os dois métodos?

OBS: Pergunto isso pois recentemente li um artigo onde uma pessoa fazia uma comparação com XML e JSON e em certos casos o JS era mais rápido trabalhando direto com XML. Então as vezes fazemos só porque é moderno!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Vantagem em colocar código direto no elemento

Uma das dificuldades que tenho com o jQuery, é na manutenção de código que não fui eu quem fiz.

O problema está em identificar onde estão no javascript, o código dos handlers associados via jQuery, de forma que ligar as pontas depois do código já estar pronto pode se mostrar uma tarefa extremamente cansativa.

Esse problema é evitado ao colocar o código direto no elemento, nem que seja para chamar um método, que fará todo o resto... na verdade essa é a forma que eu recomendaria, de forma a separar todo o restante do script em um arquivo externo, que possa tirar vantagem do cache do navegador.

### Vantagem em utilizar o jQuery para associar eventos

Em termos de organização, usar associação de eventos via jQuery é melhor, pois permite que o HTML (apresentação) fique separada das funcionalidades (comportamento). Assim sendo a *apresentação* fica desacoplada do *comportamento*.

Usar o jQuery também é mais prático, e portanto mais produtivo em várias ocasiões.

- Com ele é possível atribuir vários handlers a um mesmo evento, o que não é possível colocando o código diretamente no elemento, pelo menos não de forma fácil.
- Com ele é possível associar eventos a múltiplos elementos ao mesmo tempo, usando seletores de classe, por exemplo.

A separação total, em um arquivo de script externo tem outra vantagem, que para mim, é a principal: cache do arquivo js... mas isso não é uma vantagem do jQuery, já que na outra alternativa, isso também é possível.

### Qual das alternativas é melhor

Como quase tudo em que há várias alternativas para se escolher: use o bom senso. Vai depender do objetivo. Basta alinhar o objetivo com essas vantagens e desvantagens, além de outras que você identificar.

Pessoalmente acho plausível usar ambas as opções, desde que, com bom senso.

Comment: @Downvoter: poderia explicar o que tem de errado nesta resposta?

Answer (score 0):

É sempre melhor você deixar o `JavaScript` <strike>desvinculado</strike> separado do `HTML`, assim como `CSS`. Em relação a funcionalidade, o resultado será o mesmo, é mais uma questão de organização e praticidade.